# Iterative file name in bash

Tags: bash

I want to iterate over different file names. The file names are XY1.txt, XY2.txt...XY500.txt. Each file that is taken as input generates 3 output files which I want to rename according to the current index. For XY1.txt, output1.txt becomes 1_1.txt, output2.txt becomes 1_2.txt and so on. But I do not know how to change the filename as per index. I looked it up but I was not finding what I needed on this website or elsewhere. I am new to bash. The below pseudo code is what I was able to write until now. Please help me out

```
    for i in {1..500} ; 
         filename = "XY"+str(i) + ".txt"  ;
         do ./CompiledCodeFile  -filename -use_option 4; 
         mv output1.txt str(i)+"_1.txt"   ;
         mv output2.txt str(i)+"_2.txt"   ;
         mv output3.txt str(i)+"_3.txt"   ;
    done
```

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of things that are wrong, let me correct it.

Comment: Edit: Removed the typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..500}
do
    filename="XY$i.txt"
    ./CompiledCodeFile  "$filename" -use_option 4
     mv output1.txt "${i}_1.txt"
     mv output2.txt "${i}_2.txt"
     mv output3.txt "${i}_3.txt"
done
```

**notes:**

- `$i` and `${i}`, what's the difference?

They're the same thing, but sometimes you need to use the `${}` for differentiating the variable name from the following letters (here the `_`)

- Why use double quotes for expanding variables, for example `"$filename"`?

Because that's *almost* **mandatory**. Not using double quotes is the cause of a lot of errors, while using double quotes can only be wrong for a very few cases *(the only ones that I can think of is `[[ xyz == $regexp ]]` and the likes)*.

<sub>***edited** following @MikaelKjær comment.*</sub>

Comment: I saw some Bash scripts for other uses where they use a semi colon. Why is that not necessary here ?

Comment: You can use a semi-colon OR a newline for separating commands

Comment: @MikaelKjær : ShauryaGoyal is a new bash user, so I can't possibly **not** use double quotes in my answer, even if it is not mandatory in his specific case...

Comment: To be clear, I'm not criticizing you using quotes - I encourage it. It's the note I'm criticizing since it's just plain wrong. Your answer would be better without the second note.

Comment: @MikaelKjær : Well, my initial note was like a conclusion without prior explanations. Is it better after the edit?

Comment: No. It's very inaccurate. The reason to use double quotes is to prevent word splitting and it's generally seen as a good practice. I don't see any reason to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `seq 500`; do
mv output${i}.txt ${i}_${i}.txt
done
```

1. use seq function to generate integer from 1 to 500
2. In bash, the type of variable is string in default.

Comment: `seq` is not a function. It is an external application, though not specified by POSIX, a common utility. It is superfluous to spawn an external application to do some counting and then pass that application's output to `bash` for word splitting. In `bash`, C-style `for` loops are the best method for implementing a counter: `for ((i=1; i<=500; i++))`

Comment: And the script  doesn't do what the OP asked for.